# Can I use Gorilla Epoxy to fill epoxy resin?

Tags: kitchen-counters

I just used epoxy resin on my counters and there are a few small imperfections.  Was hoping I could use this small, syringe style 2 part epoxy to fix it rather than doing another flood coat.

Comment: No, it'll show real bad if you do that.  The epoxy systems also may not play well together.   Consult with the epoxy system manufacturer about what to do about flaws, unless you are certain you caused them by an error and you can fix the error.

Comment: A picture of the imperfections would also be greatly beneficial is helping you.

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/BfWVR2Dq124bF2g49

Comment: I know it's user error by skimping on the flood coat, but was just hoping this cheap, easy Gorilla Epoxy would work.